# Как узнать серийный номер телефона или планшета в swift?

Tags: swift

Как узнать серийный номер аппарата (телефона или планшета) в swift?

Какая функция вернула бы мне серийный номер телефона или планшета?

Comment: Какого аппарата? В этот вопрос следует включить больше подробностей и уточнить проблему.

Comment: Не пойму какая функция вернула бы мне серийный номер телефона или планшета

Answer (score 1):

Никак. Такой возможности у разработчика нет.

Comment: Вот тут немного подробностей и альтернатива - https://stackoverflow.com/a/24506906/77764

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример кода на Swift для Mac OS  возможно это сработает и на телефоне и планшете:

```
var serialNumber: String? {
  let platformExpert = IOServiceGetMatchingService(kIOMasterPortDefault, IOServiceMatching("IOPlatformExpertDevice") )

  guard platformExpert > 0 else {
    return nil
  }

  guard let serialNumber = (IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperty(platformExpert, kIOPlatformSerialNumberKey as CFString, kCFAllocatorDefault, 0).takeUnretainedValue() as? String)?.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines) else {
    return nil
  }


  IOObjectRelease(platformExpert)

  return serialNumber
}
```

Подробнее можно узнать [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52982791/how-to-get-the-device-serial-number-in-object-c-or-in-swift)

Comment: Не сработает, об этом даже сказано по приведенной вами ссылке